# Error reading XML with MHP and XleTView

Tags: java, xml, interactive

I am making an application as homework for my course for interactive TV using Osmosys (an implementation of MHP) as middleware.

I'm trying to read an XML file using:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder(); 
Document doc = db.parse(file);
```

When I run it with the XleTView (an emulator) it says:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Lxjava/io/File;)Lorg/w3c/dom/Document;

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Class that you are using don´t works in MHP (mph use java 1.3 i think), Use NanoXML.

Hi, MHP uses java 1.1 until java 1.3 I think..., so when you call a class that is not are soported at this distribution show (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError...). To solved you could use the NANOXML.